# Enter elements into dynamic (pointer-defined) array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, cin, element

I want to ask a question regarding entering elements in a dynamic array. I declare an array and then I want to enter elements in it. How can I do this using pointers into the array `arr[]` that I have declared previously?
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int *n = new int ;
int main()
{

    cin>>*n;
    int *arr = new int[*n];

    int *i=new int;
    for(*i=0; *i<=*n; *i++)
    {
        //Here, I should enter the elements but I cannot figure out how?
        cin>>(*arr+i);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need pointers for the size, or the index. Also consider using `std::vector`

Comment: You should *definitely* invest in a good C++ beginners book. This is terrible code.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;`, use `std::vector<T>` rather than `new T[]`, use automatic storage whenever you can, prefer `x[i]` rather than `*(x+i)` and if you have that many unary `*` operators in your code, you should rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am not changing your original approach at all so that you can understand pointer concept a bit more clear. As you know that array and pointer address calculation are exactly same. First you need to calculate the address and then dereference it. You just need to change it like below:-

```
   cin>>*arr++;
```

Also you need to change your `for` loop like below:-

```
for(*i=0; *i<=*n; (*i)++)
```

But now after the above `for` loop you are going to face problem. The reason is that after storing each element in `arr` we have incremented the address of `arr`(arr++), so after the end of `for` loop `arr` is now pointing to the last element ( because arr = arr+*n). So first simply try with the below code:-

```
 cout<<*arr<<endl<<endl;
```

if you have entered five numbers for example 0,1,2,3, and 4 the above statement will print some junk value as pointer is increment one more time.

now try with below:-

```
arr--;// Now arr will point to last element i.e. 4
cout<<*arr<<endl<<endl;
```

Hence you need one more `int` pointer and should store  the first address of `arr` in it like below:-

```
int *arr = new int[*n];//exactly after this line of code
int *first = arr;
```

Now use a `for` loop to print the array:-

```
arr = first; //pointing to the first eliment
for(*i=0; *i<=*n; (*i)++)
{
    //Here, I should enter the elements but I cannot figure out how?
    cout<<*arr++<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Not quite for the first one. I know it's weird, but his `i` is an `int*`

Comment: You are true, first approach will work in case of string. Corrected it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

While I question your usage of pointers for the size of the array *and* the index (They should just be `int n;` and `int i = 0;`, respectively), you can fix your code by using the subscript operator, or in code:

```
cin >> arr[*i];
```

Using pointer arithmetic is just unclear and makes it hard to tell what your goal is (In case you're wondering, the correct notation is `*(arr+*i)`, which looks horrible IMO).

On a side note, consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a container, which will make your life a lot easier and prevent you from having to deal with pointers. Usage of `std::vector` may look like:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr;

    for (int x; std::cin >> x;)
    {
        arr.push_back(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This would prevent you from having to ask the user for the size of the `std::vector` as well and allow them to keep entering elements until they enter an EOF.